# make a dotplot of differences in variables

Tags: r, dot-plot, ggformula

I cant figure out how to plot the difference between two variables, female and male, I want to make a dotplot of female - male.

my attempts so far are:

```
MyData$earn_diff <- MyData$female - MyData$male
gf_point( ~(female - male), data=MyData)
gf_point( ~(myData$female - myData$male)
```

both plots resulted in `Error: Invalid formula type for gf_point`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, when posting a question please make sure to include an example of your data, using `dput()` or using a pre-existing data set that is similar to your data. Also, please include the minimum code to make your code reproducible. It is not clear offhand what package this function is from. Finally, consider running `?gf_point()` to access the function's help page, and look at the examples section to give you a better sense as to how to use that function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ggformula::gf_point` provides a formula interface for `geom_point` and hence requires both an `x` and a `y` aesthetic aka a two sided formula, using `1 ~ ...` or `factor(1) ~ ...` will do:

```r
library(ggformula)

gf_point(~ mpg - hp, data = mtcars)
#> Error: Invalid formula type for gf_point.

gf_point(factor(1) ~ mpg - hp, data = mtcars)
```

[image]